# Find the limit of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

A sequence is recursively defined sequence.

$u_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} u_{n}$, where $u_{1} = 1$

From the monotonic bounded theorem, one can show that a limit for this sequence exists. How to compute the limit?

Comment: Let $a_n=nu_n$.  Then, $a_{n+1}=a_n$, with $a_1=1$ so that $u_n=\frac1n$.  And the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $(n+1)u_{n+1}=nu_n$ so that the sequence $(n u_n)_n$ is constant, 
thus equal to its first term $u_1$.

Therefore $u_n=\frac{u_1}{n}$ and $\lim_n u_n = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for response. Could you provide some general strategy tips?

Comment: @AngleQian this answer does not generalize well. It was just a 'trick' that kills the problem instantly. Maybe briefly look for such tricks in your future assignments. A general method would be to take limits on both sides, but it's inefficient in this specific case.

Comment: Could you provide the method that involves taking the limit from both sides? Thank you.

Comment: +1. Simple.${}{}{}{}{}$